# How to correctly assign a Token for a session in Autocomplete

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

Below I put the code for Autocomplete and downloading place for the selected item.

I create a Token (at the time of creating an Activity) and save it in another class (Singleton).

I assigned the token in the appropriate places, as in the documentation.

But the session doesn't work. When I enter 8 letters in the search field, the number of Places API requests increases by 8.

[Interface API Cloud image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFClN.png)

And it should be 1.

**The error must be somewhere in the adapter itself because even if I do not click any item on the list, it immediately counts 1 request per character.**

When something is selected from the list, I automatically create a new Token

```
UtilsWayo.searchToken = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance()
```

**AutoCompleteAdapter**

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction> implements Filterable {

    private List<AutocompletePrediction> mResultList;
    private PlacesClient placesClient;

    AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, PlacesClient placesClient) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1);
        this.placesClient = placesClient;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        row.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);

        AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

        parent.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.border_out_bottom_left_right));

        TextView textView1 = row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView textView2 = row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        if (item != null) {
            textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText( null));
            textView1.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            textView1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#32A3F0"));
            textView2.setText(item.getSecondaryText(null));
            textView2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#32A3F0"));
        }

        return row;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                // We need a separate list to store the results, since
                // this is run asynchronously.
                List<AutocompletePrediction> filterData = new ArrayList<>();

                // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
                if (charSequence != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                    filterData = getAutocomplete(charSequence);
                }

                results.values = filterData;
                if (filterData != null) {
                    results.count = filterData.size();
                } else {
                    results.count = 0;
                }

                return results;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {

                try {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                        mResultList = (List<AutocompletePrediction>) results.values;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                // Override this method to display a readable result in the AutocompleteTextView
                // when clicked.
                if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                    return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getFullText(null);
                } else {
                    return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private List<AutocompletePrediction> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {

        //Create a RectangularBounds object.
        RectangularBounds bounds = RectangularBounds.newInstance(
                new LatLng(18.62556 - 0.1, 54.380443 + 0.1),
                new LatLng(18.62556 + 0.1, 54.38044 + 0.1)
        );

        final FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest requestBuilder =
                FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                        .setOrigin(new LatLng(18.62556, 54.38044))
                        .setCountry("PL")
                        .setLocationBias(bounds)
                        .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
                        .setSessionToken(UtilsWayo.searchToken)
                        .setQuery(constraint.toString())
                        .build();

        Task<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse> results =
                placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(requestBuilder);


        //Wait to get results.
        try {
            Tasks.await(results, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (results.isSuccessful()) {
            if (results.getResult() != null) {
                Log.d("SESSION TOKEN IN REQUE ",  requestBuilder.getSessionToken().toString());
                Log.d("SESSION ADAPTER XXX",  results.getResult().getAutocompletePredictions().toString());

                return results.getResult().getAutocompletePredictions();
            }
            return null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
private val autocompleteClickListener =
    OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
        try {
            val item = adapter!!.getItem(i)
            var placeID: String? = null
            if (item != null) {
                placeID = item.placeId
            }

            // To specify which data types to return, pass an array of Place.Fields in your FetchPlaceRequest
            // Use only those fields which are required.
            val placeFields = listOf(
                Place.Field.ID,
                Place.Field.NAME,
                Place.Field.ADDRESS,
                Place.Field.LAT_LNG
            )
            var request: FetchPlaceRequest? = null
            if (placeID != null) {
                request = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(placeID, placeFields)
                    .setSessionToken(UtilsWayo.searchToken)
                    .build()
            }
            if (request != null) {
                placesClient!!.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener { task ->
                
                UtilsWayo.searchToken = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance()

                    task.place.latLng?.let {
                        getDirections(UtilsWayo.currentLocation, it)
                    }

                    UtilsWayo.currentLocation = UtilsWayo.currentLocation

                    task.place.latLng?.let {
                        UtilsWayo.destinationLocation = it
                    }

                    val myBounds = LatLngBounds.Builder()
                    myBounds.include(task.place.latLng)

                    mMap.moveCamera(
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                            myBounds.build(), 150
                        )
                    )

                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17.0f))

                    // Marker celu
                    mMap.addMarker(
                        task.place.latLng?.let {
                            MarkerOptions()
                                .position(it)
                        }
                    )

                }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    responseView.text = e.message
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```